# Dimension of shape in conv1D

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have tried to build a CNN with one layer, but I have some problem with it.
Indeed, the compilator says me that

> ValueError: Error when checking model input: expected conv1d_1_input
> to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (569, 30)

This is the code

```py
import numpy
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv1D

numpy.random.seed(7)

datasetTraining = numpy.loadtxt("CancerAdapter.csv",delimiter=",")
X = datasetTraining[:,1:31]
Y = datasetTraining[:,0]
datasetTesting = numpy.loadtxt("CancereEvaluation.csv",delimiter=",")
X_test = datasetTraining[:,1:31]
Y_test = datasetTraining[:,0]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(2,2,activation='relu',input_shape=X.shape))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=150, batch_size=5)
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)

print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

Answer (score 136, accepted):

**td; lr** you need to reshape you data to have a *spatial* dimension for `Conv1d` to make sense:

```
X = np.expand_dims(X, axis=2) # reshape (569, 30) to (569, 30, 1) 
# now input can be set as 
model.add(Conv1D(2,2,activation='relu',input_shape=(30, 1))
```

Essentially reshaping a dataset that looks like this:

```
features    
.8, .1, .3  
.2, .4, .6  
.7, .2, .1
```

To:

```
[[.8
.1
.3],

[.2,
 .4,
 .6
 ],

[.7,
 .2,
 .1]]
```

**Explanation and examples**

Normally convolution works over spatial dimensions. The kernel is "convolved" over the dimension producing a tensor. In the case of Conv1D, the kernel is passed over the 'steps' dimension of every example.

You will see Conv1D used in NLP where `steps` is a number of words in the sentence (padded to some fixed maximum length). The words would be encoded as vectors of length 4.

Here is an example sentence:

```
jack   .1   .3   -.52   |
is     .05  .8,  -.7    |<--- kernel is `convolving` along this dimension.
a      .5   .31  -.2    |
boy    .5   .8   -.4   \|/
```

And the way we would set the input to the conv in this case:

```
maxlen = 4
input_dim = 3
model.add(Conv1D(2,2,activation='relu',input_shape=(maxlen, input_dim))
```

In your case, you will treat the features as the spatial dimensions with each feature having length 1. (see below)

Here would be an example from your dataset

```
att1   .04    |
att2   .05    |  < -- kernel convolving along this dimension
att3   .1     |       notice the features have length 1. each
att4   .5    \|/      example have these 4 featues.
```

And we would set the Conv1D example as:

```
maxlen = num_features = 4 # this would be 30 in your case
input_dim = 1 # since this is the length of _each_ feature (as shown above)

model.add(Conv1D(2,2,activation='relu',input_shape=(maxlen, input_dim))
```

As you see your dataset has to be reshaped in to (569, 30, 1)
use:

```
X = np.expand_dims(X, axis=2) # reshape (569, 30, 1) 
# now input can be set as 
model.add(Conv1D(2,2,activation='relu',input_shape=(30, 1))
```

Here is a full-fledged example that you can run (I'll use the [Functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/))

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Conv1D, Dense, MaxPool1D, Flatten, Input
import numpy as np

inp =  Input(shape=(5, 1))
conv = Conv1D(filters=2, kernel_size=2)(inp)
pool = MaxPool1D(pool_size=2)(conv)
flat = Flatten()(pool)
dense = Dense(1)(flat)
model = Model(inp, dense)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

print(model.summary())

# get some data
X = np.expand_dims(np.random.randn(10, 5), axis=2)
y = np.random.randn(10, 1)

# fit model
model.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: if i have data with dimension 1x690, and I implement a Conv1D layer with 40 filters of kernel size 3, when I look up the weights of that layer, it says I have 40*690*3 weights. I'm not sure I understand why this is, I thought I would only have 40*3 weights? How does it output a 1x40 shape?

Comment: @parsethis, actually, your functional example worked even without reshaping X. Only using a sequential approach I managed to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 8):

I have mentioned this in other posts also:

To input a usual feature table data of shape `(nrows, ncols)` to Conv1d of Keras, following 2 steps are needed:

```
xtrain.reshape(nrows, ncols, 1)
# For conv1d statement: 
input_shape = (ncols, 1)
```

For example, taking first 4 features of iris dataset:

To see usual format and its shape:

```
iris_array = np.array(irisdf.iloc[:,:4].values)
print(iris_array[:5])
print(iris_array.shape)
```

The output shows usual format and its shape:

```
[[5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2]
 [4.9 3.  1.4 0.2]
 [4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2]
 [4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2]
 [5.  3.6 1.4 0.2]]

(150, 4)
```

Following code alters the format:

```
nrows, ncols = iris_array.shape
iris_array = iris_array.reshape(nrows, ncols, 1)
print(iris_array[:5])
print(iris_array.shape)
```

Output of above code data format and its shape:

```
[[[5.1]
  [3.5]
  [1.4]
  [0.2]]

 [[4.9]
  [3. ]
  [1.4]
  [0.2]]

 [[4.7]
  [3.2]
  [1.3]
  [0.2]]

 [[4.6]
  [3.1]
  [1.5]
  [0.2]]

 [[5. ]
  [3.6]
  [1.4]
  [0.2]]]

(150, 4, 1)
```

This works well for Conv1d of Keras. For `input_shape (4,1)` is needed.

Answer (score 3):

I had a sparse matrix as input, so I couldn't reshape it without casting to usual array

The solution was to use the keras Reshape layer:

```
from keras.layers.core import Reshape

...
model = Sequential()
model.add(Reshape((X.shape[1], 1), input_shape=(X.shape[1], )))
model.add(Conv1D(2,2,activation='relu'))
...
```

Comment: Only your support got me to compile. All of the other answers would still take me to the original error:
ValueError: Error when checking model input: expected conv1d_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (569, 30)

Answer (score 2):

Without being able to see more detail your data is not in the right shape after preprocessing.
Reshape X to have 3 dimensions:

```
np.reshape(X, (1, X.shape[0], X.shape[1]))
```

Comment: My dataset is formed from 30 attributes,2 classes and 569 value.
I dont' understand where I have to reshape my X

Comment: So are the values of your array `0`s and `1`s?

Comment: In X array I have the values of attributes, in Y I have only 0 and 1.
The shape of X is (569, 30) while Y is(569,)

Comment: You can reshape you array just after your preprocessing steps (if you have any). `X = np.array(X).reshape(1, X.shape[0], X.shape[1])`

Answer (score 0):

For sparse matrix, in my case, rows: 73196, column : 101 I used reshape function of numpy after converting my sparse matrix to array by `array_ = sparse_matrix.A` then I used below code

```
x_train_all = np.reshape(array_ , (73196, 101,1))
```

and in the input layer I used below code:

```
input2 = Input(shape=(101,1), dtype='float32', name='input2')
```