# Keras Conv1D: error of dimensions

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, deep-learning, keras, convolution

I am trying to perform a rating using the CNN template.

I have 150 classes. My train base has 19470 rows and 1945 columns. It is an matrix that contains 0 and 1.

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv1D
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(150,kernel_size=3,input_shape(19470,1945),activation='linear',padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))



model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

This raises:

> ValueError:  Error when checking input: expected conv1d_39_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (19470, 1945)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dimension of shape in conv1D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43396572/dimension-of-shape-in-conv1d)

Comment: I can not do it!

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your xtrain shape?

According to the error that keras is raising you should do: `x_train = xtrain.reshape(19470, 1945, 1)`

I don't understand why are you using as many layers of conv1d as classes you have?
I can't give advice on the architecture of your NN, but I your last layer should be a **Dense** layer with **150 units** and **softmax** activation. Don't you have 150 classes?